# How do I verify a Firebase sessionCookie (JWT) using jose?

Tags: firebase, jwt, jose

### Setup

1. I'm following [the docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies).
2. I'm using [Next.js middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware) which means I cannot use Firebase functions to verify my cookie. So, I'm attempting to verify it with [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose).
3. The Firebase docs state

> ensure that the session cookie was signed by the private key corresponding to the token's kid claim. Get the public key from https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys and use a JWT library to verify the signature.

### What I've tried

```
// middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
import * as jose from 'jose'

export async function middleware(request) {
  // Check the cookies
  const allCookies = request.cookies.getAll()
  console.log(allCookies)

  // Get the sessionCookie (if it exists)
  const sessionCookie = request.cookies.get("sessionCookie")
  console.log("sessionCookie", sessionCookie)

  // Test verification using a hard-coded public key from 
  // https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys
  const alg = 'RS256'
  const spki = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIDHDCCAgSgAwIBAgIEIhgI5zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAzMQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZH
  aXRraXQxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdvb2dsZSBJbmMxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMB4XDTE5MDEx
  NDIzMjgzMVoXDTIwMDEwOTIzMjgzMVowMzEPMA0GA1UEAxMGR2l0a2l0MRMwEQYD
  VQQKEwpHb29nbGUgSW5jMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzCCASIwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQAD
  ggEPADCCAQoCggEBAMLh7U8PNsOebb1HVLDa81W/CZK8DrdYl9Vlwj/0/GF7kfLP
  zF4qyShw1zAZddlzt7f6lDy2ZvmQ1nqW0IRy8xgYTeAb6aCLY+rm4DEnwJOCnAVo
  m1xpgcOVExsXXpleWsP0MugM5xa91Y79CYkVTevPZThgjqfGjan3GiXLQwIJTLG8
  xEXXSzmMDeW6dP6CBVPsbbTYSat6CX2nBm2YoJ4v2dij3DQBzOD/d5WLaYL4yE9p
  TjmreitFvs1r0AZF53Cq5ju7M10indVyk1zwfK+tuk7VnCZz/mBHEPxT9+Q5EWFi
  lVVkZ+2Qau0qRIvar/1QukVpyEsVHPZH+aZ9ilMCAwEAAaM4MDYwDAYDVR0TAQH/
  BAIwADAWBgNVHSUBAf8EDDAKBggrBgEFBQcDAjAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCB4AwDQYJ
  KoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAH4ca9fhlBd9XmaX9E0rZ8QCWT8AnxcVLY+S+nHJg2IT
  dj7ZytNJWttKEssOdslrQyamxt2SdQSfpd2UpA+fCO2sRSJOBEA3squGrj1yh1Pt
  lajf2TM1MwpdO7ZqBbfE3hLH7srBbVXHxKsUemepxviC+dpF0u4o3EjqHpAvkruO
  4RtC4grbFBNRIbBTu7oJHpKnBJWxK7w11a5Sabs6reAuFh68QaVAQzrscYP/M4i9
  SPwArWKoCJgrxxVof1N1cal4UpziEH9OaWa7RfyZTYAeEJ/atDo5s8AACPUH542f
  JEwmwAJKbJKLRoFYJJXCPeKp1Q7EXQHJNNdS2ABjw+w=
  -----END CERTIFICATE-----`

  const publicKey = await jose.importSPKI(spki, alg)
  const { payload, protectedHeader } = await jose.jwtVerify(sessionCookie.value, publicKey)
  
  console.log(protectedHeader)
  console.log(payload)
}
```

This produces the error

> error "spki" must be SPKI formatted string

### Questions

1. How do I make this work?
2. Why does https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys provide not one, but five different public keys?
3. Each public key appears to have a unique (key, value) pair. For example

   ```
   "skIBNg": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIDHDCCAgSgAwIB...vb2dsZSBJbmMxCzAJBgNVBAYTA.f+9Vg=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
   ```

   What is the purpose of the *key* `"skIBNg"`? I'm not currently using it.

Comment: I just realized that the JWT header includes a *kid* like `skIBNg`. This kid tells you which one of the five public keys to use. Furthermore, I needed to use `jose.importX509()` to make this work. I'll post my code tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

The JWT header includes a *kid* like `skIBNg`. This kid tells you which one of the five public keys to use.

Furthermore, I needed to use `jose.importX509()`, not `jose.importSPKI()`. (The giveaway was `BEGIN CERTIFICATE` in the string as opposed to `BEGIN PUBLIC KEY`).

Here's some incomplete code to make this work.

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import * as jose from "jose";

export async function middleware(request) {

  // Get the sessionCookie (if it exists)
  const sessionCookie = request.cookies.get("sessionCookie");

  // Decode header
  const protectedHeader = jose.decodeProtectedHeader(sessionCookie.value)
  
  // Decode payload
  // const claims = jose.decodeJwt(sessionCookie.value)

  // Make sure the alg header is RS256
  // Make sure the kid header is in the public_keys keys
  if (!(protectedHeader.alg == "RS256" && protectedHeader.hasOwnProperty('kid'))) {
    NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/signin', request.url))
  }

  // Fetch public keys
  const publicKeysResponse = await fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/publicKeys")
  const publicKeysData = await publicKeysResponse.json()

  // Get the correct public key
  const x509 = publicKeysData[protectedHeader.kid]
  const { alg } = protectedHeader

  // Validate and fetch the payload
  const ecPublicKey = await jose.importX509(x509, alg)
  const { payload } = await jose.jwtVerify(sessionCookie.value, ecPublicKey)

  // ...
}
```